# How do you craft the freedom staff?

Tags: team-fortress-2

On TF2, I would like to know how to craft the freedom staff. Can it be a random melee for all class besides engie and spy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can craft it like most other weapons. It doesn't have it's own blueprint, but you can still make it using Fabricate Class Weapons, which takes one Scrap Metal, one Class Token, and one Slot Token. The Slot Token has to be Melee for it, obviously. The Class Token can be of any type except Engineer and Spy, but Sniper Tokens will give the highest chance. Since he only has three other melee weapons currently, you'll have a 25% chance of crafting it with that.

See also: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Freedom_Staff#Crafting

Answer (score -1):

I used a sniper class token, a melee slot token, and one scrap.

Crafted it first try.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a Q/A, not a message board. Please only comment on unanswered questions or an answer better than one of the questions.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot craft this staff.
Not Craftable, was a promo only.

http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Freedom_Staff

Comment: No, it is craftable as of the latest update.